# Flex Direction Column Not Working In Safari (-webkit-box-orient: vertical; has been added)

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

For the life of me I cannot seem to discover the root of this problem.  The site in question is here: http://perfectashot.com/

The sections that are utilizing flex - the intro, the blue squares, the app, and the order section - aren't going into a column layout on mobile.  I'm using autoprefixer to take care of my cross browser issues, and after searching some other topics I tried to set -webkit-box-orient: vertical; manually (this hasn't been pushed to the live site, sorry) Regardless of my efforts nothing seems to be taking effect.

If anyone has any ideas, or if I'm just an idiot and missing something glaring please let me know.  Thanks.